# How slow are function calls?

Tags: c++

I'm coding a real-time graphics application in C++, so efficiency is very important.
Now I always wondered how expensive is a function call itself? (for instance a function that has zero parameters)

I currently have this big function I wrote that can either be very long in code because I tried to avoid as many "helper function" calls as I could, or be much shorter and easier to read but includes many helper function calls.

I must note that this "big function" may be called hundreds and or even thousands of times per second.

Comment: Depends on your application, your system, and your requirements. I don't think you're going to get much more than "time it and see" from random people on the internet, unfortunately...

Comment: You have heard of inlining right? Compilers are much better at it then you, so just let it do its job.

Comment: A functions time is too fast to describe. Probably on the average computer well over 100,000 a second. And as above, inline functions will put the function wherever it is called within your code. You could test it. Time start, then loop a function call, say, 20,000 times, find end time, and you'll have an idea.

Comment: The thing is, actually all my helper functions take at least 2 parameters. That includes copying of 8-12 bytes in every call. There is also the return value which also takes time to copy.

Comment: tell your compiler to inline the functions - that gives you nice clean coding but no function overhead

Comment: @Pilpe you don't need to worry about that, the computer computes way faster. Your code will run instantly.

Comment: rather that ask why not measure it - its easy to do and the answer will depend on platform, processor and language

Comment: @pm100 Measuring how long a function call takes is not easy at all.

Comment: @Pilpel the question should be, how fast are function calls

Comment: @nwp you take base time, come up with a simple function that may or may not do anything at all, call it 100,000 times, see how long it takes to complete.

Comment: @nwp of course it is. Write code inline in a loop, move the inline code to a function and repeat

Comment: In both cases the function call is likely to be optimized out or drowned by statistic noise.

Comment: @nwp - which would clearly show that the overhead is negligible, or that the compiler is smart enough to optimize it away, which would answer his question. He could of course be using a compiler that is terrible at inlining and so he might see a big difference, which again would answer his question

Comment: I tested a simple function consisting of incrementing a global int. I did it in a (2^31-1)-times for loop (max int) and either inline  or with a function call. With `-O0 -fno-inline`, I got a consistent overhead of about `10-14%`, with `-O1 -fno-inline` the overhead of the function call was consistently about `200%`, further optimization levels completely optimized out the inline loop (runtime 0 => overhead infinity).

Comment: I don't believe this question is a duplicate. The other question is about comparing the function calls with memory accesses in different storage places.

Comment: I figure the overhead will probably be constant time (e.g., the percentage will be much smaller (practically negligible) for functions that do more than just increment a global int). Would post the benchmarks, but can't, since the question got closed.

Comment: AFAIK setting a function as inline only hints the compiler to do so. I can't know at all if the compiler chose to inline it.

Comment: @PSkocik I'm thinking the same. Can anyone remove that duplicate mark?

Comment: From my hardware background, this is one of the first benchmarks I implement on any new hardware.  On this typical Dell Demension (not particularly high performance),  In 4 seconds measurement, 5 nanoseconds per ::time(0).  (time(0) is very quick),  Other measurements subtract how many 5 ns invocations it took in the loop.   -O3,  but IMHO, time results can not be optimized out of the run time.  Conclusion - function calls durations are very small.

Comment: Some of this also depends on calling convention and the actual parameters passed in. For example, some functions, depending on the types and number of parameters, may require more data to be spilled into the stack, and that can impact performance negatively. It really depends. What I would suggest though is that worrying about the cost of function calls against modern compilers and hardware is probably the most unhealthy form of micro-optimization obsession possible -- the most likely to significantly degrade the maintainability of code with little benefit. It's far more productive, even...

Comment: ... from a micro-optimization standpoint to focus on more impacting things like memory access and spatial locality, and always with a profiler in hand. You can't go too far wrong in terms of writing efficient code by simply thinking of function calls, even indirect ones (across dylibs, function pointers, virtual functions) as being rather "free" -- use all the ones you need to get the most productivity out of your code, until you really have measurements to make an exception.